# What's the easiest method for migrating content from Drupal 7 to another Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, migrations

I have two drupal 7 sites and one of them has about 21 content types that does not exists in the other drupal 7 site. It's not a data merge so it's more of a data copy. I know there is the migrate module, but that seems a bit overkill for something like this as I am not merging data into an existing content type. It should just create a new content type on the new site and import all the fresh datas in.

What's the best approach or modules that should be used in this scenario?

I have never used migrate module before, so I'm assuming it's pretty complex as it can deal with many types of data. I remember there was a module which let you copy content from one site into the other.

The only complexity here is that these content types have node references and entity references associated to them. What issues might arise from that?

Comment: Not adding this as an answer, as it's more of an opinion. Migrate isn't actually *that* hard to set up and use, it's just got a bit of a steep learning curve. It's also really easy to preserve references through import, so if you've got a day I'd just try that one out! Node export would also mean there's still a lot of effort migrating files etc over, who have references that must also be maintained. ***tl;dr: Migrate might be a little harder to start with, but it's the right tool for this job***

Comment: i think i'll take that dive and learn migrate. what are some good tutorials you recommend that helped you?

Comment: also how does migrate deal with entity/node references during migrate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module to export the configuration for your content types (and any related things - taxonomies and the like).

To move content between the sites, I'd recommend looking into the [Deploy](https://www.drupal.org/project/deploy) module, which will allow you to "push" content from one site to another. It requires some configuration to get it all set up, but it works really well, particularly with nodes that have dependencies on other entities (via entity reference or taxonomy term reference or things like that).

If you want to use [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) (which is probably not a bad idea, depending on your data). You could also look into the [migrate_d2d](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d) module, which has a UI that let's you just point at another Drupal site, and then press "Go" and it'll pull in all your content.

tl;dr: There's lot of ways to do it, but the "best" way depends on the data in your sites.

Comment: Better link the modules you mentioned. That would help a lot!

Comment: Ah, yeah. Good call. Done!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should use the [Features module](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) in order to migrate content types and fields.

Indeed, the migrate module might be too much for what you're trying to do as your datas are already Drupal formated. Instead, you could use the [node export module](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export) to export and import the datas of your nodes.

If you use Entity Reference, you might need the [Universally Unique IDentifier (UUID) module](https://www.drupal.org/project/uuid) in order to make sure that your Entity Reference won't get lost during import in your new site (new node id will be affected to your nodes imported).

Comment: what about node / entity references? wouldn't that be an issue since those are linking to another node-id on the old system and the node-id might be different on the new system.

Comment: I thing you should look into Drupal UUID to solve that.